# How to drag an image after drop onto HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I've modified a page where I can drag and drop images onto a canvas.  It does everything I want except for one.  I've tried multiple methods (including scripts, e.g. Kinetic and Raphael, which I still think may be the route to go) but have dead ended:

**Once the image is dropped, I can't drag it on the canvas to a new position.**

```
function drag(e)
{
    //store the position of the mouse relativly to the image position
    e.dataTransfer.setData("mouse_position_x",e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft );
    e.dataTransfer.setData("mouse_position_y",e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop  );

    e.dataTransfer.setData("image_id",e.target.id);
}

function drop(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = document.getElementById( e.dataTransfer.getData("image_id") );

    var mouse_position_x = e.dataTransfer.getData("mouse_position_x");
    var mouse_position_y = e.dataTransfer.getData("mouse_position_y");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // the image is drawn on the canvas at the position of the mouse when we lifted the mouse button
    ctx.drawImage( image , e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - mouse_position_x , e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - mouse_position_y );
}

function convertCanvasToImage() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    var image_src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(image_src);

}
```

Here is a JSFiddle that I used as my initial start point - http://fiddle.jshell.net/gael/GF96n/4/ (drag the JSFiddle logo onto the canvas and then try to move it).  I've since added CSS, tabs, content, etc. to my almost working page. The function I don't want to lose is the ability to drag the single image multiple times (clone) onto the canvas.

Any ideas/examples/pointers on how to create this functionality?

Comment: I did the same functionality. For this you need to draw image again and again at the dragged position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a couple of changes to your code, instead of drawing the image immediately to the canvas, you need to keep track of all images dropped. `imagesOnCanvas` will be filled with all images dropped.

```
var imagesOnCanvas = [];

function drop(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = document.getElementById( e.dataTransfer.getData("image_id") );

    var mouse_position_x = e.dataTransfer.getData("mouse_position_x");
    var mouse_position_y = e.dataTransfer.getData("mouse_position_y");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    imagesOnCanvas.push({
      context: ctx,  
      image: image,  
      x:e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - mouse_position_x,
      y:e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - mouse_position_y,
      width: image.offsetWidth,
      height: image.offsetHeight
    });

}
```

You also need an animation loop, which will go through all images in `imagesOnCanvas` and draw them sequentially. `requestAnimationFrame` is used to achieve this.

```
function renderScene() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height
    );


    for(var x = 0,len = imagesOnCanvas.length; x < len; x++) {
        var obj = imagesOnCanvas[x];
        obj.context.drawImage(obj.image,obj.x,obj.y);

    }
}

requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
```

Next you will have to monitor `mousedown` events on canvas, and if the event occurs on an image the `startMove` action can be called

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var downX = e.offsetX,downY = e.offsetY;

    // scan images on canvas to determine if event hit an object
    for(var x = 0,len = imagesOnCanvas.length; x < len; x++) {
        var obj = imagesOnCanvas[x];
        if(!isPointInRange(downX,downY,obj)) {
            continue;
        }

        startMove(obj,downX,downY);
        break;
    }

}
```

The `isPointInRange` function returns true if the mouse event occurred on an image object

```
function isPointInRange(x,y,obj) {
    return !(x < obj.x ||
        x > obj.x + obj.width ||
        y < obj.y ||
        y > obj.y + obj.height);
}
```

Once 'move mode' is active, the x/y coordinates of the object are changed to reflect the new mouse position

```
function startMove(obj,downX,downY) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    var origX = obj.x, origY = obj.y;
    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
        var moveX = e.offsetX, moveY = e.offsetY;
        var diffX = moveX-downX, diffY = moveY-downY;


        obj.x = origX+diffX;
        obj.y = origY+diffY;
    }

    canvas.onmouseup = function() {
        // stop moving
        canvas.onmousemove = function(){};
    }
}
```

Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XU2a3/41/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Tried the code with the following and see almost the same results in JSFiddle: IE 8.0 - No canvas displayed.  Nothing works.  FF 17.0 - First image drags and drops.  Disappears when trying to move. Subsequent images drag and drop but do not move. Generate Image does not work.  Chrome 23 - Drag and Drop works. Can move images after drop on canvas. Generate Image does not work.  Safari 5.1.7 - Drag and Drop does not work. Generate Image opens a new window but can't tell if it is fully functional without being able to drop an image.  Any advice on what to do to fix?

Comment: lostsource - your jsfiddle seems to work with chrome on jsfiddle but when I copy the code (with or without closing </html>) and run it from a file or webserver it doesn't.  Did you make a change (I don't see any) and What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: No changes were made to the fiddle, make sure the image you're dragging comes from the same domain as you might have security issues related to cross domains. (the image in that sample comes from jsfiddle domain)

Comment: Arrrrgh!! Rookie mistake.  Works in Chrome now.  Now to figure out how to get it to work cross-browser.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: if you have issues not related directly to the original question I think it would be better to post them as separate questions.

Comment: Nope...no more questions on this one.  Thanks again for the help. Learned quite a bit from your response.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been like 2 years, but I'll give it a try... In the answer provided by @lostsource, the dataTransfer object is not supported in Opera browser, and the jsfiddle is not working. I desperately need that answer, that's what I've been looking for, but it's not working!