# Allowing the drag after dropping an image onto canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop

```
$(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// get the offset position of the container
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var Offset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = Offset.left;
var offsetY = Offset.top;

// select all .tool's
var $tools = $(".tool");

// make all .tool's draggable
$tools.draggable({
helper: 'clone',
revert: 'invalid'
});


    // assign each .tool its index in $tools
$tools.each(function (index, element) {
$(this).data("toolsIndex", index);
});

// make the canvas a dropzone
$canvas.droppable({
drop: dragDrop,
});

// handle a drop into the canvas
function dragDrop(e, ui) {

// get the drop point (be sure to adjust for border)
var x = parseInt(ui.offset.left - offsetX);
var y = parseInt(ui.offset.top - offsetY);

// get the drop payload (here the payload is the $tools index)
var theIndex = ui.draggable.data("toolsIndex");

// drawImage at the drop point using the dropped image 
ctx.drawImage($tools[theIndex], x, y, 32, 32);

}
});
```

I tried many things but I failed. This code allows me to drag and drop multiple images onto a canvas element. What I need to do is to add the possibility of dragging the image again after it's been dropped. I know that the canvas has to be redrawn each time, but I didn't know how.

Can anyone fix this for me?

Comment: What do yo mean *'dragging the image again'*? You mean starting the drag once in the canvas?

Comment: The images I'm dragging are not in the canvas element. I drag from outside the canvas (an accordion actually), and drop onto the canvas element. So, once they're inside the canvas I can't move them anymore, I need them to be draggable, to change their position (for the flexibility of the application).

Comment: You mean that once you drop them, they are removed from the accordion, but you want them to still be there so you can drag them again?

Comment: No, this is not the issue, I can drag the same image multiple times. I want to reposition them once they're dropped in canvas, using the mouse, so obviously I'll be needing event handlers, which I tried and didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drag an image after drop onto HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578657/how-to-drag-an-image-after-drop-onto-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you commented that you're open to canvas libraries, here's an example that lets you:

- drag an img element from a toolbar-div using jqueryUI.
- drop the img on the canvas and create a `KineticJS.Image` object that you can drag around the canvas.

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gkefk/

Results: An img dragged 3X from blue toolbar, dropped on gray canvas, and then dragged on the canvas.

[image: result screenshot]

Here's a commented code example:

```js
$(function() {

  // get a reference to the house icon in the toolbar
  // hide the icon until its image has loaded
  var $house = $("#house");
  $house.hide();
  
  

  // get the offset position of the kinetic container
  var $stageContainer = $("#container");
  var stageOffset = $stageContainer.offset();
  var offsetX = stageOffset.left;
  var offsetY = stageOffset.top;

  // create the Kinetic.Stage and layer
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);

  // start loading the image used in the draggable toolbar element
  // this image will be used in a new Kinetic.Image
  var image1 = new Image();
  image1.onload = function() {
    $house.show();
  }
  image1.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeibZ.png";

  // make the toolbar image draggable
  $house.draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
  });

  // set the data payload
  $house.data("url", "house.png"); // key-value pair
  $house.data("width", "32"); // key-value pair
  $house.data("height", "33"); // key-value pair
  $house.data("image", image1); // key-value pair

  // make the Kinetic Container a dropzone
  $stageContainer.droppable({
    drop: dragDrop,
  });

  // handle a drop into the Kinetic container
  function dragDrop(e, ui) {

    // get the drop point
    var x = parseInt(ui.offset.left - offsetX);
    var y = parseInt(ui.offset.top - offsetY);

    // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
    var element = ui.draggable;
    var data = element.data("url");
    var theImage = element.data("image");

    // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
    // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
      name: data,
      x: x,
      y: y,
      image: theImage,
      draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(image);
    layer.draw();
  }

}); // end $(function(){});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

#container {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

#toolbar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 35px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/4.7.2/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prototype</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <img id="house" width=32 height=32 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeibZ.png"><br>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code is not working .Drop opeation is not perform.

Comment: @markE Can I remove it dropped image in some condition?

Comment: @jserodio. Yeah. This demo is from 2+ years ago and the KineticJS library no longer exists so  the link to KineticJS in my demo has rotted. KineticJS has morphed into [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io/) so the demo will likely work if you link to KonvaJS. Cheers!

Comment: @jserodio. I looked up an old cdn for KineticJS and updated the demo so it should be again working (until the cdn rots -- argh).

Comment: @markE thank you so much for the heads up. It is fully working now

Answer (score 1):

What you want is certainly not easy. Now you just drop the image and draw it in the mouse position. To do what you want, you'll need:

1. Keep track of the images added, their positions, their sizes, and their z-index. The best way to do this is using a stack structure, an array of objects with this properties: `url` `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`. The z-index can be the index of the array.
2. Once you start a drag operation on the canvas, you need to get the point you're dragging, and find the image with the highest z-index that contains that point (basically, implement hit-testing).
3. To move it, then you have to remove it from the canvas, which implies redrawing the entire canvas with all the images except the one you're dragging. For this you can use the stack previously defined, and draw the images in order.
4. Finally, you need to draw your image again once you drop it, take it from its position in the array and append it at the end.

This is not an easy task. I suggest you to use some library for it. I cannot recommend you one, because I have little to no experience with canvas.

Comment: At first I decided to work with EaselJS library, and I ended up doing it with pure JS and jQuery. I did not find good documentation on this library, it's always simple demos, and as you see the app I'm working on requires more than those demos. Thank you :-)

Comment: I wish I could help you with more code, but I can't promise, because it would take some time and I'm not sure if I have the time.